# How does Reiner's girlfriend Malkina profit from the hijacking in The Counselor?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-counselor

I am really confused about this, that how does she profit from the hijack? I am confused because maybe I don't understand when she hijacks the delivery. There are two hijacks of trucks. First time when a guy takes the shipment from the courier guy on the road and takes control of the truck, imo this is when Malkina hijacked because that's how she put the suspicion on the counselor, or second time when two guys appearing as cops take the truck from the first guy who took the shipment. But, if she hijacked it first time then it got hijacked by other guys then how does she profit?

Considering the possibility that she hijacked it second time then how did she know about the plans of the first hijacker and whereabouts of the truck when it got hijacked first time?

The whole movie makes sense only when she hijacked it second time and got the money at the end by selling it back to the cartel or its client, but I don't understand how it aligns with the events.